# How to check button is enable or disable on Webbrowser control C#

Tags: c#, html

I have a problem while running navigate on web browser.

I view source:

***Case 1 (When button is Disable):***

```
<button aria-label="" class="Button-main_f70bc854 Button-primary_60d9bace Button-hasMinWidth_2a8fbb9a Redemption-buttonPrimary_b0ca4ab9" id="" title="" type="submit" disabled=""><span><span>Redeem</span></span></button>
```

***Case 2 (when button is Enable) :***

```
<button aria-label="" class="Button-main_f70bc854 Button-primary_60d9bace Button-hasHover_352bd025 Button-hasMinWidth_2a8fbb9a Redemption-buttonPrimary_b0ca4ab9" id="" title="" type="submit"><span><span>Redeem</span></span></button>
```

When i get attribute "disabled" in case 2. it not working because attribute "disabled" is removed.
How to check for button status whether it's enable or disable.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: you have to check if the button has the disabled attribute

Comment: Can you help me a example code?

Comment: did you saw this ? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d6478138-f9e5-4aeb-9c14-f56990a83cba/forward-and-back-button-enableddisabled-using-the-webbrowser-control-using-vb-60net?forum=winforms